# Map custom property coming from a stored procedure function into Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, nopcommerce

I am using nop commerce e-commerce open source 1.9 in which they use the Entity Framework.

They have one stored procedure which loads all the products and map that stored procedure to `sp_ProductLoadAllPaged` function

Now I change that stored procedure and in out put of that sp their is one more column which is `languages`.

I also declare the `languages` property in product.cs class file.

But now as I use quick watch `languages` column is null for all products.

I updated the `.edmx` file from database in model browser.

Now I check that I am missing some mapping of languages attribute which in class and stored procedure

So please tell me how to map this new column of stored procedure to product class languages properties.

please see the below image for more information

[image: mapping image]

As you can check the stored procedure final select statement where I made changes to get the languages of that product

```
SELECT  
        p.ProductId,
        p.Name,
        p.ShortDescription,
        p.FullDescription,
        p.AdminComment,
        p.TemplateId,
        p.ShowOnHomePage,
        p.MetaKeywords,
        p.MetaDescription,
        p.MetaTitle,
        p.SEName,
        p.AllowCustomerReviews,
        p.AllowCustomerRatings,
        p.RatingSum,
        p.TotalRatingVotes,
        p.Published,
        p.Deleted,
        p.CreatedOn,
        p.UpdatedOn,
        p.AmazonLink,
        p.ProductCode,
        p.CategoryText,
        STUFF((Select ','+ [Name] from Nop_Language where Nop_Language.LanguageId in
    (Select Nop_ProductLocalized.LanguageID
    from
        Nop_ProductLocalized
    where
        ProductID=p.ProductId
    ) for xml path('')),1,1,'') as 'languages'
    FROM
        #PageIndex [pi]
        INNER JOIN Nop_Product p with (NOLOCK) on p.ProductID = [pi].ProductID
    WHERE
        [pi].IndexID > @PageLowerBound AND 
        [pi].IndexID < @PageUpperBound
    ORDER BY
        IndexID
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to modify the class. The new property must be known in EDMX and template from EDMX must generate that property in class for you.

So if `sp_ProductLoadAllPaged` is an entity you must manually add property in EDMX and map it. If it is a complex type you must update the complex type in function import wizard. You can also do both approaches directly in EDMX if you open it as XML (save your current version somewhere prior to doing manual changes).

Comment: if i edit the function by right clicking select edit the complex type is disable .

Comment: In such case stored procedure cannot return complex type and you must edit the entity.